# How to set path to images for use with CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

It usual that location of viewed pages is different from location of edited. So, image urls will be broken in CKEditor by default. How to set path to images so that thet displayed ok while editing page?

Comment: why don't you use an absolute url or absolute path? /full/path/to/image.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just set the [baseHref](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseHref) to the path of the final page.

Answer (score 0):

if your imagge source will start with `/` it mean domain, so for example if you put your images to `images` folder in `public_html`, your source path should be `/images/file_name.png` and it will work on website and ckeditor.